# Appium automation test: How to get element or text from custom UI in android [android.view.View]

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests, appium

I beginner test automation on Android by Appium. 
I use IUAtomatorviewer to get eLement from Android Application
But i think my applicatoin is from customs UI. i see that is
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView / android.view.View
in [android.view.View] element, 
there no text or other informatoin

i see it include TextView, Image... same a item in listview

Here is my code

```
AndroidElement el = driver.findElement(By.id(io.***.vodi:id/message_list_item_chat_id));
AndroidElement el2 = (AndroidElement) el.findElementByClassName("android.view.View");
el2.getText(); //result is blank
el2.getAttribute("text") //result is blank
```

so
how do i get text inner [android.view.View] ? or attribute of View

Here image of UIAutomatorviewer
[image]
[image]

Comment: though I doubt its because of the `RecyclerView` used during development, still i hope you are not ending up looking at an entirely different `View` on UIAutomatorViewer

Comment: Which android sdk version you are using ?

Comment: I think updating to latest sdk and UIAutomator it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Get the "recycler view" by its resource-id.  You can then get the different view's inside and select the 4th one to view "view #4".

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue in getting text from android view. below code helpful for me:

Get all your element in a list :

```
List<WebElement> allChats : driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.view.View']"));
```

Then iterate through for loop and get the text using ***`name`*** attribute

```
for(WebElement chat : allChats)
{
     System.out.println(chat.getAttribute("name"));
}
```